# How do I set up a "Mailing List Only" option in CiviCRM 5.29.1?

Tags: wordpress, civicontribute, civimember

In addition to setting up paid Membership Sign-up, I am trying to create a free "Mailing List Only" option. I created a contribution page entitled "Mailing List Only", created a "Mailing List Only" Price Set and even a "Mailing List Only" Financial Type so that I could set the price to $0.00.  But when I try to test-drive the page, I get the following message:

"The requested online contribution page is missing a required Contribution Amount section or Membership section or Price Set. Please check with the site administrator for assistance."

I am using CiviCRM 5.29.1 and WordPress 5.5.3 running Blocksy theme.

I hope someone can help me!

Answer (score 2):

Welcome to StackExhcange MABB. The Documentation of CiviCRM should provide all the information you need to set up a mailing subscription page: https://docs.civicrm.org/user/en/latest/email/set-up/.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you so much, Fabian!